# Solac Single thread C Application

Tags: c, multithreading, solace, solace-mq

Just now started using C APISolac. But I found that application will be multithread if I am using solac.
I  have C Application which is single thread and have multiple connections (eg, TCP,UDP, FILE, timerfd) I am polling using epoll. which have dependency on each other. I wanted to use Solac as another connection on epoll. I want to keep my application as single thread cause it have dependencies. Please someone help me if it possible to use Solac connection in single thread.

Regards,
Sayed Momeen

Comment: Do you mean Solace API? https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/c/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a separate context thread for FD processing and all things internal to the Solace C API is the default behaviour.

This can be changed in various ways, but do read up on "Selecting a Threading Model" and "File Descriptor Management" in https://docs.solace.com/Solace-PubSub-Messaging-APIs/Developer-Guide/C-API-Best-Practices.htm

Assuming that you want to run `epoll_wait()` yourself and manage the API's FDs, below is a guideline of what is needed. This assumes a single context.

1. Disable automatic creation of the context thread.

   ```
   contextProps[ctxtIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_CONTEXT_PROP_CREATE_THREAD; 
   contextProps[ctxtIndex++] = SOLCLIENT_PROP_DISABLE_VAL;
   ```
2. Fill `solClient_context_createFuncInfo_t` in `solClient_context_create()` with your own FD management functions:

   - `solClient_context_registerFdFunc_t` and
   - `solClient_context_unregisterFdFunc_t`.

   The former is for `EPOLL_CTL_ADD/MOD` and registering callback function, the latter is for `EPOLL_CTL_DEL/MOD`. Note:

   - `SOLCLIENT_FD_EVENT_ALL` ~ `EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT`
   - `SOLCLIENT_FD_EVENT_READ` ~ `EPOLLIN`
   - `SOLCLIENT_FD_EVENT_WRITE` ~ `EPOLLOUT`

   The Solace C API will register its own FD event callbacks through those defined functions.
3. In your main epoll loop:

   - `epoll_wait()` with timeout = `SOLCLIENT_CONTEXT_PROP_DEFAULT_TIME_RES_MS`
   - call `solClient_context_timerTick()` every `epoll_wait()` timeout
   - make callbacks to FD events

Look up the Solace C API reference for more details on the symbols stated in this answer:
https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/c/index.html